# Question Edited by another user, adding info that wasn't there before?

Tags: discussion

This question

[Employer asked me to leave the job in 30 days](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/76843/employer-asked-me-to-leave-the-job-in-30-days)

If you look at the edit history, you'll see that it's been edited by user58078, and the edit was approved.

The problem as I see it is that this information wasn't given by the OP, so where did it come from and why was it approved?

Answer (score 6):

It's fairly common for someone to suggest an edit as an anonymous user to their own question, if they registered an account and lost information/etc.

[This meta post elsewhere](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2129/31251) has a lot of good explanation.

> So it's basically ok to change the content and meaning of someone else's question/answer, just as long as you do it anonymously and assume that the reviewers will think it's the OP who's forgotten their password?

No, it's not ok. I don't know why you think it would be ok to blatantly troll another user for... fun, I guess?

If you (or others) see what appears to be someone doing this, please flag the post so as moderators we can investigate and correct the issue.

Comment: So it's basically ok to change the content and meaning of someone else's question/answer, just as long as you do it anonymously and assume that the reviewers will think it's the OP who's forgotten their password?

Comment: @Pete - when you say it that way, it does indeed seem foolish to allow anonymous changes.

Comment: Yes, I certainly looks that way from the point of view of a non-moderator.  It seems likely that a moderator approved the edit based on IP/cookie lookups (anon user = OP).  From my viewpoint, the approved edit looks not different from a non-mod looking at the edit review screen and just stabbing the "OK" button.  I'm guessing that the question of allowing anonymous editing has been long discussed and approved (I have no idea why though).

Comment: @enderland Thanks for the extra information. I can now see this could have been a moderator approval and the edit was the OP.  However, I don't agree that unregistered users should be allowed to edit posts - it makes no sense at all to me, especially as the "forgot password" process is so simple.

Comment: In my experience, even as a moderator, the overwhelming majority of users on Stack Exchange are well intentioned. I am far less worried about malicious users suggesting anonymous edits than I am new users being confused by the interface or losing access to their first account. While I am sure there have been edits suggested intentionally in this way, I suspect it's a very small percentage of the total edits. Maybe I'm too optimistic (I am always smiling, after all ;).

Comment: @enderland Also, SE is famous for shutting down trolls to the point many don't bother, and they communicate to other trolls that we are just no fun.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the users who approved this edit, I'll confirm that my thoughts were exactly as enderland suggests: by far the most likely case is that this was from the OP having somehow screwed up their registration - it happens all the time. Let's not worry about the remote possibility that this might have been a "malicious" edit until it can be shown that this actually happens on a regular basis.

I'll also note I left a comment for the OP explaining what they *should* do in this situation; they've had plenty of opportunities to shout if there were *actually* a problem here. Right now, this meta post seems to be worrying about an imagined problem, with no evidence presented that there is any actual problem at all. Let's move on until that evidence appears.

As an aside, my recollection is that the edit *wasn't* from an anonymous account when it was made. You'd need someone who understands that SE process more than I do to explain what happened there.

Comment: Thanks Philip.  It looks as though the thread has now been closed and the added edits have now been removed by another moderator.  I agree that this situation probably doesn't happen that often, but I'm still somewhat surprised that anonymous users are allowed to edit posts.  Users who go through the effort of creating an SE account must surely be able to handle the "forgotten password" routine that's so prevalent on every online community.  Especially this guy who says he's a computer programmer.  But, I guess this is how the SE world works and I shouldn't really get too worried about it.